# How to Convert Feet to meter in JS on Document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calc

I think its simple but i dont find any solution

```
<p class="number">12</p>
```

How can i simply automatically calc at "document ready" to meter?

I dont need a button just a simple calculation

Comment: 1) Add code that will run at the document ready event. 2) Select the p tag with the class 'number'. 3) Parse it's innerText to a number. 4) Convert that number into it's equivalent in feet. 5) Write the result back into the p tag.

Comment: Unclear? I need a automatic calculation at page load from feet to meter. No Button or something else

Comment: I know... but what i should write? Its not more than a simple calc function :)

Comment: Each of the neccesary steps explained above is found in basic javascript tutorials.

Comment: Yes and i dont get it to work...

Comment: $(".number").text(parseFloat($(".number").text() / 3.281));

Answer (score 2):

> Here is Simple solution for you.....

```
<script>
        $('#number').ready(function() {
             // Do your calculation here
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert between feet and meters, you need to use calculation. In JavaScript, you don't need a `calc()` function like in CSS. You just do it straight away.
These are what you are looking for:

### Feet to Meter

```js
var footToMeterConversionRate = 0.3048;

var number = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
number = parseFloat(number);

var newNumber = number * footToMeterConversionRate;
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = newNumber;
```

```html
<a id="number">20</a> feet is equal to
<a id="number2"></a> meters.
```

### Meter to Feet

```js
var footToMeterConversionRate = 3.2808399;

var number = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
number = parseFloat(number);

var newNumber = number * footToMeterConversionRate;
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = newNumber;
```

```html
<a id="number">20</a> meters is equal to
<a id="number2"></a> feet.
```

Note: If you want to round the numbers, use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Only HTML Form Controls

The following HTML tags have special behavior that when applied within a `<form>` tag can calculate user data:

> ```
> <form oninput="out.value = (Math.round(10000*(feet.value / 3.281))/10000)">
>
>   <input id="feet" type="number"> 
>
>   <output id="out" for="feet"></output>
>
> </form>
> ```

The `[for="ID OF INPUT"]` attribute of [`<output>`](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/html-output/#HTML_output_Tag_Main_Tips) allows it to sync with the value of the `<input>` (determined by its `#ID`). The [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) ties in all values in a callback function of an **[on-event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)** registered to an **[`oninput` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)**.

---

### Demo

```css
#feet {
  text-align: center;
  width: 8ch
}
```

```html
<form id='conv' oninput="out.value = (Math.round(10000*(feet.value / 3.281))/10000)">

  <label for='feet'>Feet: </label>
  <input id='feet' type='number' min='0.000'>

  <label for='meter'>Meter: </label>
  <output id='out' for='feet'></output>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple measurements you want to convert on your page and you want to convert all of them, you can use classes.

The example below will use a mix of types of measurements.

```js
var feet = document.getElementsByClassName("feet-to-meters");
for (var i = 0; i < feet.length; i++) {
  feet[i].innerHTML = parseInt(feet[i].innerHTML) * 0.3048;
}
var meters = document.getElementsByClassName("meters-to-feet");
for (var i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
  meters[i].innerHTML = parseInt(meters[i].innerHTML) * 3.2808399;
}
```

```html
20 feet is equal to <a class="feet-to-meters">20</a> meters<br>
30 meters is equal to <a class="meters-to-feet">30</a> feet<br>
10 feet is equal to <a class="feet-to-meters">10</a> meters<br>
40 meters is equal to <a class="meters-to-feet">40</a> feet<br>
```

Comment: thanks, exactly thats what i need! Now i need to round